# Cloud Firestore for .net Maui IOS support? facing errors

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.ios, maui

I can't find any support for fireStore Database on IOS in .net Maui. I tried f-miyu / Plugin.CloudFirestore on .net maui app on IOS using Firebase.Core.App.Configure(); after that if I call CrossCloudFirestore.Current.Instance the app stops and i get an error:

> "This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this
> assembly"

I tried the NuGet packages Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudFirestore , Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore , Plugin.Firebase.Tmp nothing is working.

Comment: You can try to use [Plugin.Firebase](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase#pluginfirebase).The new plugin version 1.2.0 now supports .NET MAUI applications with .NET 6.